# Recorded audio is not playing in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to record audio using xamarin forms:

I have this code in my xaml:

```
   <StackLayout  Spacing="15">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Switch x:Name="TimeoutSwitch" 
                    IsToggled="True" />
            <Label Text="Stop after silence?"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <Button x:Name="RecordButton" 
                Text="Record" 
                Clicked="Record_Clicked"/>

        <Button x:Name="ReproduceButton" 
                Text="Play"  
                Clicked="Reproduce_Clicked" 
                IsEnabled="False"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

This is my code behind:

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        AudioRecorderService recorder;
        AudioPlayer player;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var mainDir = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;

            recorder = new AudioRecorderService
            {
                StopRecordingAfterTimeout = true,
                TotalAudioTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                AudioSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
            };

            player = new AudioPlayer();
            player.FinishedPlaying += Finalize_Reproduction;
        }

        public async void Record_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!recorder.IsRecording)
                {
                    recorder.StopRecordingOnSilence = TimeoutSwitch.IsToggled;

                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;
                    ReproduceButton.IsEnabled = false;

                    // Start recording
                    var audioRecordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();

                    RecordButton.Text = "Stop Recording";
                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;

                    await audioRecordTask;

                    RecordButton.Text = "Record";
                    ReproduceButton.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;

                    // stop recording ...
                    await recorder.StopRecording();
                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }

        public async void Reproduce_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var filePath = recorder.GetAudioFilePath();

                if (filePath != null)
                {
                    ReproduceButton.IsEnabled = false;
                    RecordButton.IsEnabled = false;

                    player.Play(filePath);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }


        public void Finalize_Reproduction(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReproduceButton.IsEnabled = true;
            RecordButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

I have been following this tutorial: https://julianocustodio.com/2019/04/26/gravar-audio/

When I run it, its not recording and playing the audio, am I doing something wrong here? 
I am new in Xamarin, and I don't know know my way around packages.

Comment: Which platform are you trying this on?

Comment: I am using android

Comment: Download the source file from the GitHub. https://github.com/juucustodio/Audio-Recorder-Xamarin.Forms I test the code. It works well. Pleaase check your permission. Have you allowed the permission at runtime?

Comment: WOW @WendyZang-MSFT this works when I use It in a mobile phone, I was using my emulator only, and cant figure out whats wrong.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT how can I save it to the database and play it later though?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, there is no need to save. The Audio would be saved by default.
When you play it, you could get the path first and then play it.

Get the path:

```
var filePath = gravador.GetAudioFilePath();
```

Play:

```
reprodutor.Play(filePath);
```

Location:

```
/data/user/0/br.com.julianocustodo.audiodemo/cache/ARS_recording.wav
```

If you want to save it bu yourself, you could use the `GetAudioFileStream` to get the stream and then save it to your own database or just get the path and then play it.

**Updated:**

```
 var stream = gravador.GetAudioFileStream();

        string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "sample.wav");

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
        reprodutor.Play(fileName);
```

I do some change with the code of `Reproduzir_Clicked` event. The code i provided save the recorded audio with my own name `sample.wav`. And i play it to check it exists or not. It works well.

**UPDATED:**

Create a new page `Page1`, pass the filename from MainPage to Page1. The code still based on the `Audio-Recorder` on GitHub.

`Audio-Recorder`: https://github.com/juucustodio/Audio-Recorder-Xamarin.Forms

MainPage.xaml

```
  <StackLayout  Spacing="15">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Switch x:Name="TimeoutSwitch" IsToggled="True" />
            <Label Text="Parar após silêncio?" />
        </StackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="GravarButton" Text="Gravar" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="Gravar_Clicked" />
        <Button x:Name="ReproduzirButton" Text="Reproduzir"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="Reproduzir_Clicked" IsEnabled="False" />
    <Button x:Name="btnGoToPage1" Text="GoToPage1" Clicked="btnGoToPage1_Clicked"></Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    AudioRecorderService gravador;
    AudioPlayer reprodutor;
    public string fileName { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "sample.wav");
        gravador = new AudioRecorderService
        {
            StopRecordingAfterTimeout = true,
            TotalAudioTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
            AudioSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        };

        reprodutor = new AudioPlayer();
        reprodutor.FinishedPlaying += Finaliza_Reproducao;
    }

    async void Gravar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!gravador.IsRecording)
            {
                gravador.StopRecordingOnSilence = TimeoutSwitch.IsToggled;

                GravarButton.IsEnabled = false;
                ReproduzirButton.IsEnabled = false;

                //Começa gravação
                var audioRecordTask = await gravador.StartRecording();

                GravarButton.Text = "Parar Gravação";
                GravarButton.IsEnabled = true;

                await audioRecordTask;

                GravarButton.Text = "Gravar";
                ReproduzirButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                GravarButton.IsEnabled = false;

                //parar a gravação...
                await gravador.StopRecording();

                GravarButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //blow up the app!
            await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }

    async void Reproduzir_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{
        //    var filePath = gravador.GetAudioFilePath();

        //    if (filePath != null)
        //    {
        //        ReproduzirButton.IsEnabled = false;
        //        GravarButton.IsEnabled = false;

        //        reprodutor.Play(filePath);
        //    }
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    //blow up the app!
        //    await DisplayAlert("Erro", ex.Message, "OK");
        //}

        var stream = gravador.GetAudioFileStream();



        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
        reprodutor.Play(fileName);
    }


    void Finaliza_Reproducao(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReproduzirButton.IsEnabled = true;
        GravarButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void btnGoToPage1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
```

Page1.xaml

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Page1!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Text="Play" Clicked="btnPlay_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    AudioPlayer reprodutor;
    private void btnPlay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = new MainPage().fileName;
        reprodutor = new AudioPlayer();
        reprodutor.Play(fileName);
    }
}
```

It works well on my side, try it.

Comment: I want to record the audio and then, I'll save it to the  database, then I'll play it later. It is also confusing because I want my recorded audio to be labeled.

Comment: all the recorded audio file extensions are .wav?

Comment: yes, this is the default way provide by the Plugin.AudioRecorder.

Comment: but can I rename the recorded audio? instead of ARS_recording.wav maybe something like Textbox.text() +.wav? so every time I save an audio it will have a unique name

Comment: You could save the recored audio by yourself with the stream catch from `GetAudioFileStream` with your own name.

Comment: can you provide a sample code? if it works I will mark as answer, I cant seem to understand the docus

Comment: what im planning to do here is, save the speech and play it on another page.

Comment: It is easy to get, i would upload the code sample ASAP.

Comment: WOW! this worked, but I have a list of texts, if i click a list item it will go to another page, then I can play that audio there, thats why I need to save it to the database, is this possible?

Comment: I also tried: entry.text + ".wav" but it wont save it like that, I printed it on a label to see the file path. It only has /.wav in file path

Comment: It's easy to get. Use the ItemSelected event of listview. When you click the item, navigate to another page and play the record with the filaname.

Comment: I tried that and it works, but only 1 rec, the current record is the record for all the items on the listview, as I've said earlier, I tried todo: Entry.Text + ".wav" but the record will be ".wav" only. I printed it on a label to see the file path.

Comment: I found that you could has solved from the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387323/rename-a-recorded-file-every-time-i-save-a-record-in-xamarin