# Rename a recorded file every time I save a record in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am saving my records using this code:

```
        string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        fileName = Path.Combine(path, "sample.wav");

        if (!recorder.IsRecording)
                {
                    recorder.StopRecordingOnSilence = TimeoutSwitch.IsToggled;

                    //Start recording
                    var audioRecordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();

                    BtnDoneRec.IsEnabled = false;

                    await audioRecordTask;

                    RecEditor.IsEnabled = true;
                    BtnDoneRec.IsEnabled = false;
                    PlayButton.IsEnabled = true;

                    var filePath = recorder.GetAudioFilePath();

                    if (filePath != null)
                    {
                        var stream = recorder.GetAudioFileStream();

                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        }
                    }                  
                }

                else
                {                                                     
                    //stop recording ...
                    await recorder.StopRecording();                    
                }
```

I want my record to have a specific name which is labeled with my RecEditor

```
         using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
         {
            File.Move("sample.wav", RecEditor.Text + ".wav");
         }
```

So it will rename "sample.wav" to "RecEditor text.wav" every time I click my save button.
But when I click save, it gives me this record

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file '/sample.wav'.'
```

The record is stored in /storage/emulated/0/sample.wav

[image]

The sample.wav is created in my device but I don't know why it give me 'Could not find file '/sample.wav'.' error. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking is something like this:

```
if(File.Exists(fileName))
{    
    var newFileName = Path.Combine(path, $"{RecEditor.Text}.wav");
    File.Move(fileName, newFileName);
}
```

You don't need to open a new `Stream` as you are doing. Also, you need to put the full file path not only the file name.

You might want to validate that `RecEditor.Text` is not empty before using its value for the `newfileName`

Hope this helps.-

Comment: This is what I am looking for :D :D THANK YOU!